# angularjs directive controller $element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

i see angularjs highly suggested not to do any dom manipulation in the controller,
only setting the state of the scope, example pulling data from ajax etc,

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

what about directives controllers with a isolated scope 
does it make sense to set functions on the isolated scope to do dom manipulation

example

```
controller:function($scope,$element){
    $scope.editDom = function(){
        $element.someThing();
    }
}
```

Comment: directives are made for dom manipulation.

Comment: @phylax i know what directives are made for, the questions is if adding methods to isolated scope to do dom manipulation is good practice

Comment: Do you want to export a dom manipulating function from your directive controller to be called from your controller?

Comment: Keep it out of the controller. Even if that controller is within a directive, it's still a controller. That being said, you can chain on to the directive.

Comment: @phylax i want to wrap some dom manipulation logic to be able to call later , where is to place to save this method ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually I try to split directive logic into pure logic, which goes into controller, and dom manipulation logic which goes into link function.

In cases where I need to put methods which do dom manipulation on scope I declare those functions in the directive link function.

This is some what artificial separation of logic, for which the main driver is writing unit tests as then I can easily write tests that checks the controller.

In cases where my entire logic is dom manipulation and I don't need to expose api to other directives (via require) I don't have controller at all, only link.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try an answer with putting the function in a 'private' variable of the `directive`:

```
angular.module('...', [])
  .directive('...', function () {
    var
    myDOMManipulations = function (…) {…};

    return {
      scope: {},
      controller: function ($scope) {
        myDOMManipulations(…);
      }
    };
  });
```

It all depends on what the function needs to do and when it should be called.

Mostly i put even the `controller` or `link` function in a private variable so the `return { … }` gets minimal. For functions it usually doesn't matter where they are defined. Besides if the function shouzld be exported as an API.